# MongoDB java drivers not compatible in Android

Tags: android, mongodb

I am trying to delete a document from MongoDB (database present at http://mlab.com) through my Android application, but since [mongo-db-java-drivers](https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/releases/org/mongodb/mongodb-driver/3.2.2/) are not compatible with Android so therefore I am getting different `Exceptions`. So please tell is there any way to delete from MongoDB through Android application?